# Trying to automate logging into a website, going to a url, and pressing a button

Tags: javascript, automation

I manually clear around 20 tables every morning and am looking to automate the process. I am using Atom for code editing and automating the task with Task Scheduler. I do not get any errors, but the table is also not being cleared.

```
function clearProject() {  
// Open new page
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "openURL", url: 'url'});
//Login
jQuery("#cphContent_lblUsername").val("username");
jQuery("#cphContent_tbPassword").val("password");
document.querySelector("#login");
// Go to project
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "openURL", url: 'table url'});
//Purge project
jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnPurgeActivity").submit();
};
clearProject();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). It's a nice tool to automate browser tasks like you're trying to do. Doing it manually (and especially with jQuery) is probably going to take up more time and nerves instead of just learning to use puppeteer.

Comment: I had looked at puppeteer, Selenium and Playwright in the past and didn't see a way to have it run at a specific time on specific days (4 am Sun - Fri for example). Did I just miss that option?

Comment: What about Microsoft Power Automate?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aly and welcome to the community! If you're using a windows, you should check out [Windows Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/). I think it comes pre-installed and it's super simple to use.
Also it's no-code, so you only use their blocks.